# If $f$ is continuous on $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ which is bounded by $\partial\Omega$ does it follow that $\int_\Omega f \, d\Omega<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ which is bounded by $\partial\Omega$, does it follow that $\int_\Omega f \, d\Omega < \infty$? I know that the statement holds in 1d but does it also generalize to arbitary dimensionality?

Comment: The statement does not necessarily hold in 1D... If $\Omega$ is closed and bounded, it holds both in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. The statement "bounded by $\partial \Omega$ is quite vague. A set can be bounded or unbounded, but not by its boundary.

Comment: this does not even hold for $n=1$. consider $\Omega=(0,1) \ni x \mapsto f(x):= \frac{1}{x}$. Clearly $\partial\Omega = \{0,1\}$ and $\int_{\Omega}f\mathrm{d}\Omega=\infty$.
Do you maybe mean that $\int_{\partial\Omega}f\mathrm{d}\partial\Omega<\infty$? the anwer is the same since the integral then is $\mathrm{lim}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n+1=\infty$

Comment: Alirght, is there a condition that we can impose on the set such that the statement becomes true? Like compactness?

Comment: aye, compactness it is. (since f is then bounded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Omega$ is the open disk of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0),$ i.e. $\Omega = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\}.$ Then $\Omega$ is an open set, and the boundary of $\Omega$ is $\partial\Omega={}$the circle, and $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ is continuous on $\Omega,$ but $\displaystyle \int_\Omega \frac{d(x,y)}{1-x} = +\infty.$

However, if $f$ is continuous on $\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$ and that union is a bounded set, as it is, for example, if $\partial\Omega$ is a simple closed curve, then the value of the integral is finite.

If, for example, $\Omega$ is the half-plane $x<0,$ then $\partial\Omega$ is the line $x=0$ and $\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$ is not bounded. In that case, there are examples in which $f$ is continuous on $\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$ but the value of the integral is not finite.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Very clear explanation.